# Flex mobile access ios addressbook

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4.5

Is there a way to access the iphone address book with the current Flex/Air Mobile version?

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Comment: links, resources or something that could point me to some direction ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this : http://code.google.com/p/as3iphone/source/browse/trunk/Classes/com/flashiphonedevelopment/address/IPhoneAddressBook.as

Comment: Hey @Snote could you show me how to use this code to access the IPhone Phonebook?

Comment: I inly give the link. I didn't try to do it.